# TFS Build Agent failing to connect to HTTPS git in TFS 2017 when running as service

Tags: git, ssl, tfs

We are using an internal certificate on our server and I've followed the steps in

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/12/19/error-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/

as well as the steps here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/

Error when running as a service:

```
git version
git config --get remote.origin.url
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://ourtfsserver:8443/tfs/path/_git/project.extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********" fetch --tags --prune --progress origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://ourtfsserver:8443/tfs/path/_git/project/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
```

When running with the same agent config but using .\run.cmd instead of as a service (same credentials) it works successfully:

```
git version
git config --get remote.origin.url
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://ourtfsserver:8443/tfs/path/_git/project.extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********" fetch --tags --prune --progress origin
git checkout --progress --force {hash here}
(and continues onto next steps)
```

However, when I try to run it manually using our build agent account it gives the same `Git fetch failed with exit code: 128` as above. I can manually `git clone` using these credentials though.

So I've tried:

```
git config –global http.sslVerify false
```

as well as manually setting the config file to include that variable.

I've also installed the certificate using IE to get it per the 2nd blog post.

I can manually pull down the project without issue as well, both as my account and our build agent account using `git clone https://ourtfsserver:8443/tfs/path/_git/project c:\somefolder`

I'm using the TFS 2017 Update 1 RC2 From Feb 13th 2017 (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update1), the previous version wouldn't let our build agent connect at all to tfs https properly. Our old TFS 2015 build agent still works, but is missing the new features from the v2 agents.

Edit: Using `set HTTP_PROXY=https://localhost:8888` I was able to get VSTS to use fiddler as a proxy and it made one request:

```
CONNECT our.local.tfs.fqdn:8443 HTTP/1.1
Host: our.local.tfs.fqdn:8443
User-Agent: git/2.10.0 (vsts-agent-git/2.112.0)

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
(bunch of other stuff it decrypted here)
```

for Auth it had:

```
No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.

No Authorization Header is present.
```

Comment: Did you restart the build service after following the steps in the link? And a similar issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/688

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Yeah I've restarted that whole server a few times trying to get it to work :( Yeah I saw that link before and tried to do the same thing they have, also how I ended up with the blog in my OP. I wish that setting the SSL_Verify to false would work, as its internal I don't really care about SSL that much, we only enabled it because it was required by the build agent in the first place to use PAT or other auth types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a better command than disabling https verification globally, hopefully though this will be better handled in future updates to the build agent.

git config --global http."https://YOURTFS.SERVER.HERE:PORT/".sslVerify false

That will only disable it from verifying on your (hopefully internal) git server.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did to resolve the issue.

- Download latest GIT from https://git-scm.com/downloads
- During installation setup, select Windows Certificate store for SSL.
- Go to Program files and copy the latest GIT folder.
- Replace the git folder inside the agent/externals with the latest GIT
  folder.
- Restart agent and build again.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well. Are you sure you updated the correct custom trust-store? The one in the agent directory \externals\git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt ? This seems to be the one that the agent uses nowadays. So even though your system git may be working fine, the agent won't use that and thus won't trust your self-signed SSL cert.

update: if that fails too, you could try running the git.exe in there and setting the sslVerify flag to false, e.g.:

`C:\agent\externals\git\cmd\git.exe config --global http.sslVerify false`

Comment: Updating that still was a no go, but I was able to run `C:\agent\externals\git\cmd\git.exe config --global http.sslVerify false` which DID work, even though I had previously done it from the regular git path and testing it with `git config --list` showed it as disabled. If you want to add that command to your answer I'll mark it as the solution, as it did lead me to the solution

Comment: Strange! I ended up using a proper SSL cert on most of our servers due to this, because it was cheaper to do that than to remember this and change it all the time ;-)

Comment: What do you mean proper SSL cert? Paid one? We were trying to use one from our internal CA but its obviously not working well ;)

Comment: Yup, paid certs, but I reckon letsencrypt.org could work too if you have the hostname exposed.

Answer (score 1):

I have an internally issued cert (not self-signed) for TFS. Here are the steps I took to get this working for my scenario:

1. I followed step 1 of [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/), then dropped the exported cert into the certs folder, which looked something like this: E:\agent\1\externals\git\mingw64\ssl\certs.
2. After that, I followed the directions [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/) to set the git config. The command(s) for that looked like this:

   ```
   git config --global http."https://tfs/tfs/".sslCAInfo "path\to\cert\certificate.cer"
   git config --system http."https://tfs/tfs/".sslCAInfo "path\to\cert\certificate.cer"
   ```
3. The last thing I did was restart the agent service and everything was fine after that.

EDIT: I'm also running the agent under a build service domain account.

Answer (score 1):

> fatal: unable to access <server>: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer

Sometimes running the following command *appears* to work **but it hasn't!**

`C:\agent\externals\git\cmd\git.exe config --global http.sslVerify false`

To check what I mean run this:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

This will list all the Git Config files on the PC.

What worked for me is checking the **c:\ProgramData/Git/config** file.

I had to format mine (newlines and Tabs) and manually had to add the **sslVerify** and the **sslCAInfo** (for some reason in this environment they weren't getting set).

```
[core]  
    symlinks = false  
    autocrlf = true  
    fscache = true  
[color]  
    diff = auto  
    status = auto  
    branch = auto  
    interactive = true  
[pack]  
[help]  
    format = html  
[http]  
    sslVerify = false  
    sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt  
[diff "astextplain"]  
    textconv = astextplain  
[rebase]  
    autosquash = true
```

This allows a Service Account (with no login rights) to access the Git repo.

I learnt that VS2017 doesn't play well with Gits ca-bundle: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/48517/visual-studio-2017-ssl-certificate-problem-unale-t.html

Instead of this:

```
sslcainfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I use this:

```
sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
    Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Obviously when you get this going remove **sslVerify = false**

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't manually using the build agent account to run the command. Please double check if you or your mates ever modified the permission for "**Project Collection Build Service**" account. If you do not have, please add one.

[image]

Also confirm your build agent version, make sure have updated to the latest. You could use another new build agent instead of this one to narrow down the issue.

If above couldn't figured out the issue, you may need some more diagnostic info such as give a Fiddler trace.

Comment: The build service does have read permissions. The build agent works when run under my credentials when run from command, but not when using my credentials while as a service (both for login, and running as the service). In trying to troubleshoot the issue I've even set our build account "tfsbuild" as a build and project administrator. I've tried updating to the latest build agent off github (2.112.0). What kind of diagnostics info would help?

Comment: @John Since it's a connection issue, you could give a try with using fiddler to track the related info. Moreover, please check the event view on the build server if there are any useful  info. You could also create an empty build definition for test to narrow down the influence  of the build task.

Comment: Patrick, I tried to use fiddler but even when using the vsts setting `set VSTS_HTTP_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:8888` fiddler wasn't able to capture my traffic when using the agent run.cmd. Though looking at the source code now I see it might have been renamed to just `HTTP_PROXY` so the docs might be out of date. https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md. I'll try that tomorrow and see if it sheds any light on the issue... would be nice to have this build server working without having to manually log in and start the process

Comment: @John Thanks for the sharing, once you get anything, could update here.Which also help others in the community

Comment: Ok so using just `set HTTP_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:8888` did work and logged the single request to our tfs server. What information do you want from that log though? I updated the parent with a little info from it